# When we click on back button we are getting some escape character in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, html-parsing, html-email, stringescapeutils

I am using CKeditor in Java for sending email functionality. But when I am trying to add an HTML by clicking source, there is no issue in first case but after clicking Next and going Back to the same page, I am getting some Special characters as **ÃÂ ÃÂ ÃÂ |ÃÂ ÃÂ ÃÂ**. I am using following code to set the email content. I have tried all the following options one by one but none is working. 
  nCamp.setEmailContent(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(campaign.getEmailContent()).toString());
nCamp.setEmailContent(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(campaign.getEmailContent()).toString());
nCamp.setEmailContent(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(campaign.getEmailContent()).toString());

[HTML page view when added first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooth7.jpg)

[Getting Special Characters ÃÂ ÃÂ ÃÂ |ÃÂ ÃÂ ÃÂ after going back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1xZB.jpg)

These characters are also reflected in my emails. Also more times I go back to the source page, the characters are dupliating each time.

Comment: Looks more like a java question than a javascript question

Comment: Change the tag `Javascript` to `Java`. No, they are not the same thing, not even close. (Probably you know this, but I had to say).